# Reverse (outer) pandas windows

Tags: pandas

I have such a dataframe example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'sensor_value': [11, 14, 12, 2, 14, 13, 11]},
    index = [
        pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:00'),
        pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:03:00'),
        pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:06:00'),
        pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:08:04'),
        pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:10:00'),
        pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:18:00'),
        pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:20:00'),
    ]
)
```

As table:

```
                      sensor_value
2013-01-01 09:00:00   11
2013-01-01 09:03:00   14
2013-01-01 09:06:00   12
2013-01-01 09:08:04   2
2013-01-01 09:10:00   14
2013-01-01 09:18:00   13
2013-01-01 09:20:00   11
```

I would like to find those successively following each other group of rows that are larger than 10 and lasts more than 5 minutes. For example in the example above there are two groups:

```
2013-01-01 09:00:00   11
2013-01-01 09:03:00   14
2013-01-01 09:06:00   12
```

and

```
2013-01-01 09:10:00   14
2013-01-01 09:18:00   13
```

As you could notice the last row was not included into last bunch. That's because group must be closed as soon as group exceeds 5 minutes appears.

So, it looks like reverse window.

How can I solve this task?

Answer (score 3):

You can create some boolean masks to filter for the rows conditionally:

```
m1 = df.index.to_series().diff() > '5m'   # return True for rows with > 5-minute diff
m2 = m1.shift(-1)                # return True for rows just above
m3 = df['sensor_value'] > 10     # return True for rows with col values > 10
df = df[(m1 & m3) | (m2 & m3)]   # filter using and/or operators
df
Out[1]: 
                     sensor_value                           
2013-01-01 09:00:00            11
2013-01-01 09:06:00            12
2013-01-01 09:10:00            14
2013-01-01 09:18:00            13
```

Comment: Nice one. Could also avoid resetting index by making `m1=df.index.to_series().diff().gt('5m')`

Comment: @wwnde I agree that this would be better/ cleaner. Good point. I have updated my answer.